# How to create long shareable url in Dropbox SDK for Android?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm having problems when I want to generate a long shareable url to a file with Dropbox SDK for Android. I mean, I have not found a way to create that url.

For example, I have a file called `profile_image.jpg` in app folder. I upload the file with this code (like Dropbox example):

```
 public String subirImagenDropbox(File file) {

    AndroidAuthSession sesion = buildSession(); //Like the Dropbox Example
    DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(sesion);
    checkAppKey();

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        String name = file.getName();
        mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest("/empleados/img_perfil/" + name, 
            fis,
            file.length(),
            new ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public long progressInterval() {
                    return 100;
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                    System.err.println(bytes + " bytes de " + total);
                }
           });

        if (mRequest != null) {
            DropboxAPI.Entry upload = mRequest.upload(); //Here upload to Dropbox
            DropboxAPI.DropboxLink share = mApi.share(upload.path); //Generate short shareable URL. Expire in 31 days
            System.err.println("URL: " + share.url); //Print in LogCat for debug purpose

        }
    } 
    //... A lot catchs ...

    return ""; //Return the long shareable URL
 }
```

This code upload the file perfectly, but the shareable url is like this:

```
http://db.tt/abcd123
```

and I want (I added `?dl=1`):

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/abcdefghi1234567/profile_image.jpg?dl=1
```

(I added `?dl=1`).

I did it with Java SDK (`dbxClient.createShareableUrl(metadata.path)`) but in Android is different. I hope someone can help me with this minor inconvenience.

Thanks!

Comment: (Cross-linking for reference: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=119010 )

Comment: Thanks @Greg! I'm the same person who asked in Dropbox Forum! jeje